# Probability of last digit in multiplication

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If  n  integers  taken  at  random  are multiplied  together,  show  that  the  chance  that  the  last  digit  of  the  product
is 1, 3, 7, or 9 is $\frac{2^{n}}{5^{n}}$; the chance of its being 2, 4, 6 or 8 is $\frac{4^{n}-2^{n}}{5^{n}}$; of its being 5 is $\frac{5^{n}-4^{n}}{10^{n}}$; and of its being 0 is $\frac{10^{n}-8^{n}-5^{n}+4^{n}}{10^{n}}$.

I am not able to proceed, the word random complicates the question.

Comment: Try is with small cases first like n = 4 or n=3.  Also note.  If *any* number is 5 and any number is even then it will be 0.  You can figure that out.

Comment: depends on what random means in math there's a specific meaning related to distributions at last check.

Comment: I suspect that it just means that for each of the factors, the last digit is equally probable ( $p= \frac {1}{10}$ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bear with me.

Let's do cases.

The probability that the last number is odd is $(\frac 12)^n$.

The probability that the last number is even is $1 - (\frac 12)^n$

To end with $5$, one number must be five and the rest must be odd.  This is a conditional probability question.  Given that all numbers are odd then the probability of a specific number not being $5$ is $\frac 45$. The probability of all not being $5$ is $(\frac 45)^n$.  And the probability of at least one $5$ is $1 - (\frac 45)^n$.

So the probability the last digit is odd and not $5$ (i.e. is 1,3,7, or 9) is $(\frac 12)^n*(\frac 45)^n = \frac {2^n}{5^n}$ and of being odd and  $5$ is $(\frac 12)^n*(1-(\frac 45)^n) = (\frac 12)^n(\frac {5^n}{5^n} - \frac {4^n}{5^n} = \frac {5^n - 4^n}{10^n}$

To  not be  $0$ means that there are no $5$ and no $0$.  The probability of that is $\frac {8^n}{10^n} = \frac {4^n}{5^n}$.  Given that, the probability of a number being even is $\frac 12$.  So the probability of no evens is $\frac 1{2^n}$ of being at least one even is $1-\frac 1{2^n}$

So the probability of $2,4,6,8$ is $\frac {4^n}{5^n}(1- \frac {1}{2^n}) = \frac {4^n}{5^n} - \frac {2^n}{5^n} = \frac {4^n -2^n}{5^n}$

So the only remaining option that it ends in $0$ is $1 -\frac {2^n}{5^n}- \frac {5^n - 4^n}{10^n}-\frac {4^n -2^n}{5^n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the last digit of the product is determined by the last digits of the n numbers. Let P(n,m) denote the probability of the last digit of the  product of $n$ numbers being $m$.

First observe that $P(1,m)=\frac{1}{10}$, for $m=0,1,\cdots, 9$. The next step is to note that the last digit of n product is 1 happens if the last digit of n-1 product is 1,3,7,9 multiplied by 1,7,3,9 (their inverse mod 10). Then we have

$p(n,1)=p(n-1,1)\frac{1}{10}+p(n-1,3)\frac{1}{10}+p(n-1,7)\frac{1}{10}+p(n-1,9)\frac{1}{10}$

It is easy to find by symmetry that $p(n,1)=p(n,3)=p(n,7)=p(n,9)$.

Then we have $p(n,1)=p(n-1,1)\frac{4}{10}$. Hence $p(n,1)=\frac{2^{n-1}}{10\cdot5^{n-1}}$.

So $p(n,1)=p(n,3)=p(n,7)=p(n,9)=\frac{2^{n-1}}{10\cdot5^{n-1}}$.
Now we do $p(n,2)$. Note that $mx\equiv 2 mod 10$ has unique solution for $m=1,3,7,9$
and has two solutions if $m=2$,$m=4$, $m=6$, or $m=8$ $(2*1=1,2*6=12)(4*3=12,4*8=32)$,$(6*2=12,6*7=42),(4*8=32,8*9=72)$.

No solution if $m=5$ or $m=0$

So we have $p(n,2)=p(n-1,1)\frac{1}{10}+p(n-1,3)\frac{1}{10}+p(n-1,7)\frac{1}{10}+p(n-1,9)\frac{1}{10}+p(n-1,2)\frac{2}{10}+p(n-1,4)\frac{2}{10}+p(n-1,6)\frac{2}{10}+p(n-1,8)\frac{2}{10}$.

Again by symmetry we have $p(n,2)=p(n,4)=p(n,6)=p(n,8)$. Then by the above equation and use the formula for $p(n-1,1)$,$p(n-1,3)$,$p(n-1,7)$ and $p(n-1,9)$we have

$$p(n,2)=\frac{4}{10}\frac{1}{10}\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^{n-2}+\frac{4}{5}p(n-1,2)=\frac{1}{10}\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^{n-1}+\frac{4}{5}p(n-1,2)$$.

You can solve the recursive equation either by induction or by eigen-equation to get $p(n,2)$, then $p(n,4)=p(n,6)=p(n,8)=p(n,2)$.
Similarly for $p(n,5)$ we have the relation
$$p(n,5)=\frac{1}{10}p(n-1,1)+\frac{1}{10}p(n-1,3)+\frac{1}{10}p(n-1,7)+\frac{1}{10}p(n-1,9)+p(n-1,5)\frac{4}{10}$$

Solve it to obtain the formula for $p(n,5)$.

To find $p(n,0)$, we can  subtract the above probability from 1.